# I am getting warned about my flagging history, but my last declined flag was over a week ago

Tags: bug, flags, flag-ban

I tried to click on edit on a post on SFF, but I accidentally clicked 'flag' instead. When I went to close the box, I noticed this message on the bottom:
[image]

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!

My last declined flag was on the 8th. It is now the 16, and i'm getting this message again. Please fix this!

Note - I have been flagging today, and all of them were marked helpful.

Note #2 - it gives me the warning, but I can still submit the flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say this is intended behavior. The warning is meant to get your attention. It seems to have done a fairly good job of that.

When a user gets the flag warning, the system is trying to tell them that they need to take another look at what they're flagging. The idea is that the user gets this message and changes their behavior *before* they fall into the automated flag ban.

If you were talking about the ban itself, I'd be more inclined to agree with you. We're talking about a *warning*, though. It doesn't actively prevent you from flagging, it's just there as a gentle reminder to be careful.

It should go away fairly quickly when you start casting flags that are marked helpful.